# How to make Wix call function inside a DLL without errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, wix

My issue is that clearly windows has issues accessing the dll `InstallTools.dll` since I'm calling a function inside `OpenExeUrl`

Here is my dll content

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace InstallTools
{
   public class InstallHelper
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult OpenExeUrl(Session session)
        {
            try
            {
                var exeUrl = InstallTools.Properties.Settings.Default.EXEURL;
                // Prepare the process to run
                ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
                int exitCode = 0;
                // Enter in the command line arguments, everything you would enter after the executable name itself
                //start.Arguments = arguments;
                // Enter the executable to run, including the complete path
                start.FileName = exeUrl;
                // Do you want to show a console window?
                start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
                start.CreateNoWindow = true;

                // Run the external process & wait for it to finish
                using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
                {
                    proc.WaitForExit();

                    // Retrieve the app's exit code
                    exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var errorMessage = "Cannot open exe file ! Error message: " + e.Message;
                session.Log(errorMessage);
            }

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

The Wix file content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MySetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Sofar" UpgradeCode="c151e7ab-b83a-445f-93b2-2ab7122ea34b">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MySetup" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
    <Binary Id="InstallTools" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)InstallTools\bin\$(var.Configuration)\InstallTools.dll"/>
    <Binary Id="NotepadPlus" SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"/>
    <CustomAction Id="OpenExe" BinaryKey="InstallTools" DllEntry="OpenExeUrl" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes" />
    <!--<CustomAction Id="OpenExe" Return="ignore"  Directory="ProgramFilesFolder"  ExeCommand="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" Impersonate="yes" Execute="deferred"/>-->
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="OpenExe" Before='InstallFinalize'/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MySetup" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="myAppFile">
        <File Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
      <ComponentRef Id="myAppFile" />
      <!-- </Component> -->
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

You can notice that I'm calling the dll by building the custom action and add it to execution sequence.

```
<CustomAction Id="OpenExe" BinaryKey="InstallTools" DllEntry="OpenExeUrl" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes" />
    <!--<CustomAction Id="OpenExe" Return="ignore"  Directory="ProgramFilesFolder"  ExeCommand="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" Impersonate="yes" Execute="deferred"/>-->
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="OpenExe" Before='InstallFinalize'/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

My issue is that when I launch the installer I get this error shown in the following screenshot.
[image]

Could you please advice ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make your CustomAction class **public**:    `public class InstallHelper`.

2) Make sure that you're referencing the correct DLL, it should end up with *.CA.dll extension. Your bin folder has supposedly two dll files: `InstallTools.dll`, `InstallTools.CA.dll`.

Comment: I'm sorry @Chris Eelmaa but your fix doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Updated, what about now? You should read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx and also, execute msiexec /l* out.log to see complete log. The problem can be also platform mismatch. Is the problem custom action not getting executed at all or does the custom action just fail in the implementation? Use session.Log() to find out.

Comment: I'm sorry but still not.

Comment: Update your post with reflected changes.

Comment: @Sofiane; you didn't take care of the `InstallTools.CA.dll` issue. Note that Wix can only execute custom DLL's, not any dll. Your DLL project is supposed to output two dlls: InstallTools.dll, and InstallTools.CA.dll. If it's not doing so, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I can't get it generated. I don't know why.